# retrieve the entire column data If a particular text or pattern is matched

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup

I have particular header(specific column) need to retrieve the entire column of the header to another sheet.Is there any formula to do it.

Comment: there are around 20 sheets with that header or pattern in different column , I need to retrieve the entire data of that particular column

Answer (score 1):

We can use *MATCH()* to find the column and *INDEX()* to walk down that column.  Say we have:

[image]

and we want to retrieve the *Names*.  Pick some cell and enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$9999,ROWS($1:1),MATCH("Names",$1:$1,0))
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

*An array formula is not needed.*

**EDIT#1:**

To handle this for multiple sheets, just stack formula-blocks, one below another.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I need to fetch similar way from all the  sheets in a workbook to a single sheet. This works only if it is a single sheet.Also the column is not same for all sheets.

Comment: @Mohan  You are correct!

Comment: can u elaborate on formula blocks